# Construct a homeomorphism between $S^1/\rho$ and $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, quotient-spaces

> Construct a homeomorphism between $S^1/\rho$ and $S^1$ (the unit circle)
> where $S^1=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2=1\}$ and the equivalence relation is $$(x',y')\rho(x'',y'') \iff y''\leq 0 \text{ and } y'\leq 0.$$

I get it intuitively, I know this equivalence relation is identifying the part of the circle below and on the $x$-axis as a single class in the quotient, so is like shrinking them to single point, so that the upper part of the circle closes in the quotient, and therefore it should be homeomorphic to a circle $S^1$.

Now I am having trouble finding the expression for the homeomorphism
I think I could do some like $f(t)=(cos(2t), sin(2t)))$, with $t\in [0,\pi]$, to parametrize $S^1$ where $t$ is the arc-length of the upper half of $S^1$ , but I need to relate it to the quotiented space and write everything in cartesian coordinates.

Can someone shed some light?

The expression for f should be such that
$f(x',y')=f(x'',y'') \iff  (x',y')\rho (x'',y'')$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using polar coordinates and trying double the angle for positive $y$-coordinates, you might consider the following projection:

Inside the unit circle $C_1$ place another circle $C_2$ with center $(0,\tfrac 1 2)$ and radius $\tfrac 1 2$. Now given any $(x,y)\in C_1$ the line segment between $(x,y)$ and the origin intersects $C_2$ in a unique point. See [this illustration using GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/sfvb9dhz).

The projected point on $C_2$ stays stationary when $y\le 0$, which is exactly what you need to define your homeomorphism.

---

The unit circle $C_1$ is given by $x^2+y^2=1$, the second circle $C_2$ is given by $x^2+(y-\frac 1 2)^2 = \frac 1 4$. The line segment between $(x,y)$ and the origin consists of the points $(tx,ty)$ for $t\in[0,1]$.

Hence, the intersection point satisfies
$$
(xt)^2+\left(yt-\frac 1 2\right)^2 = \frac 1 4,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\underbrace{(x^2 + y^2)}_{=1} t^2 - yt = 0.
$$
When $y\ge 0$, solving for $t$ yields $t=0$ (the origin) and $t=y$,
corresponding to the point $(xy,y^2)$.

Now shifting and scaling yields a homeomorphism $C^2\to S^1$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto (2x,2y-1)$ that sends our intersection point on $C_2$ to
$$
\left( 2xy, 2y^2 - 1 \right).
$$

Hence, the map
\begin{align*}
S^1 &\longrightarrow S^1 \\
(x,y) &\longmapsto
\begin{cases} (2xy, 2y^2 - 1) & y > 0, \\
(0,0) & y \le 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
induces the desired homeomorphism $S^1/\rho \to S^1$.

Comment: Thanks,  I am still unable to translate it to a formula , though

Comment: I've added the details.

Comment: How do you do the  shifting and scaling part? , and you say is an homeomorphism from  $C^2\to S^1$, but we are going the other way around, starting with $ S^1$, which is what the final map shows

Comment: and how do you get $(tx,ty)$?

Comment: To map $C_2$ onto $S^1$ you shift down by $\frac 1 2$ to move the center to the origin, so $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y-\frac 1 2)$ and then scale everything up by a factor of $2$ to increase the radius to $1$, ending up with $(x,y)\mapsto(x,y-\frac 1 2)\mapsto (2x,2y-1)$. The construction I did goes $S^1=C_1\to C_2\to S^1$ and then induces a map $S^1/\rho \to S^1$. The line through two points $A$ and $B$ is always given by $A + t\cdot(B-A)$ and in case of $A=(0,0)$ and $B=(x,y)$ you just get $(tx,ty)$.

Comment: The first $S^1$ is what was called X before you edited? I got this from an exam, and I guess they had a point in calling X instead of $ S^1$, to distinguish them, even if they are the same set

Comment: Yes, $X=S^1=C_1$.

Comment: Using $(x,y)\mapsto (2x,2y-1)$ on the intersection point $(xy,y^2)$, doesn't it yield: $(2x(2y-1),(2y-1)^2)$.? but you are getting another expression

Comment: No, you are composing the maps the wrong way around. You want $(2x',2y'-1)$ for $(x',y') = (xy, y^2)$.