# A simple homeomorphism between unit circle and quotiented unit circle

Tags: general-topology, circles, quotient-spaces

> I want to show $S^1/\mathscr{R}$ and $S^1$ are homeomorphic
> where $S^1$ is the unit circle and the equivalence relation is $$(x',y')\mathscr{R}(x'',y'') \iff y''\leq 0 \text{ and } y'\leq 0.$$

Now I am having trouble finding the expression for the homeomorphism

I found the same question here
[Construct a homeomorphism between $S^1/\rho$ and $S^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3751942/construct-a-homeomorphism-between-s1-rho-and-s1)

but the solution is too long and complicated, this problem was part of a short exam and the solution is not expected to be that long and complicated

A partner suggested
$f(x,y)=(\cos(2\arccos(x)), \sin(2\arccos(y)))$ for $y>0$ and

f(x,y)=(1,0) for $ y\leq 0$

The professor didn't say it was wrong nor did he say it was right.

1. **Is this suggestion correct? or is there a simpler one?**
2. We need to map the half the unit circle to a whole unit circle and the other half to a single point and then prove surjectivity, injectivity of the funtion for $y>0$ so that the whole function passes to the quotient as injectivite,  and continuity .The homeomorphism will follow from the fact that once we know it is bijective and continuous the function will go from a compact space to a T2 space

I guess continuity ad surjectivity follows just by inspection,**How will I go about proving injectivity for $y>0$?**

Comment: That's not an equivalence relation...

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich could You elaborate? why wouldn't it? By the way it is implicit the points in the upper half circle form singleton clases

Comment: Very good point @DavidC.Ullrich. The equivalence relation has only been defined for points on the lower half where the $y$ coordinate is $\leq 0$. For full detail, one should add that for points with $y>0$ the equivalence relation is just equality. (Yes, I agree it's implicit--so the comment is mostly regarding clarity in the problem, not that something is wrong.)

Comment: @halrankard  that was implicit

Comment: @mathlover It's not an equivalence relation because as you seem to be aware, it's not true that every point is equivalent to itself. I don't care what you say is "implicit" - say what you mean.

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich  I mean the points that are not explicitly mention in the equivalence class are considered to be singleton classes, at least that is what I was taught

Comment: maybe it's not standard usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is much easier to think about this in polar coordinates since a point on the unit circle can be uniquely identified by an angle $\theta\in (0,2\pi]$. So we identify $S^1$ with the space $(0,2\pi]$ under the topology given by "circular intervals" that possibly wrap around $2\pi$. (There is an explicit homeomorphism $\theta\mapsto (\cos \theta,\sin\theta)$ that you can use to translate back and forth.) It's more convenient to use $2\pi$ for "angle $0$" in this case.

Then you can view $S^1/\mathscr{R}$ as $(0,\pi)\cup\{\ast\}$ where $\ast$ is the single point corresponding to the class of angles in $[\pi,2\pi]$.

The map your partner suggests (modulo an issue discussed below) is $f:S^1/\mathscr{R}\to S^1$ where $f(t)=2t$ for $0<t<\pi$ and $f(\ast)=2\pi$. Described out loud, this map doubles all angles in the upper half circle $(0,\pi)$ so that they cover everything in $(0,2\pi)$, and then sends $\ast$ to $2\pi$ to fill the last point.

Written this way, it is quite clear that the map is a bijection. Continuity is not hard to prove either. A basic open set is a set of the form $(r,s)$  or $(0,r)\cup (s,2\pi]$ for $0<r<s\leq 2\pi$. In the first case the preimage is $(r/2,s/2)$. In the second case the preimage is $(0,r/2)\cup (s/2,\pi)\cup\{\ast\}$ (which is open in the quotient topology since its preimage under the quotient map back to $S^1$ is $(0,r/2)\cup (s/2,2\pi]$.)

---

I will add some further details: I have identified $(0,2\pi]$ and $S^1$ to make the problem easier. Formally, the underlying map in this identification is $\theta\mapsto (\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. I *am not* saying that this is the homeomorphism you ask for in the main question. The homeomorphism is the map $f$ which is the same as your partners (modulo issue) up to this identification between $S^1$ and $(0,2\pi]$.

If you want to unwrap the identification to get a function in Cartesian coordinates then you just have to go through the trig. Start with $(x,y)$ in the upper half circle. Go polar by taking $\theta=\arccos(x)$ (which is in $(0,\pi)$). Apply $f$ to get $2\arccos(x)$. Now go back to Cartesian coordinates to get $(\cos(2\arccos(x)),\sin(2\arccos(x))$. We have our function.

Actually, going through this I can see either there is a typo or your partner didn't quite get it right: $\arccos(y)$ should be $\arccos(x)$. If it looks strange to have the map depend only on $x$ then recall that a point in the upper half of the unit circle is *completely determined* by its $x$ coordinate. So really this is a "one parameter" situation, which is all the more reason to go polar.

Comment: So is the map $f(t)=2t $ or $ f(\theta)=(cos(\theta),sin(\theta))$ ?

Comment: but you said my partner's map is $2t$, speaking out loud I agree that they both double the angle, but can it be proved analitically that they are the same?

Comment: I deleted my earlier comment since it got too long and added some details to the answer.

Comment: I get my partner's suggestion now with the correction I was also suspicious about. Then writing this in polar coordinates the map becomes f(t)=2t ? then I  also need to rewrite the equivalence relation in polar coordinates

Comment: This is a great explanation, I might just wanna emphasize to the OP that it might help to think a bit more technically about the space $S^1/\mathscr{R}$. Each element in there is an equivalence class, it just happens that for points $\theta \in (0,\pi)$, each $\theta$ is it's own distinct equivalence class. We really mean (in polar coords) $[(1,\theta)] \in S^1/\mathscr{R}$. And as @halrankard mentioned, any of $\theta \in [\pi,2\pi]$ are representatives of the same equivalence class, $[\pi]$.

Comment: and why do you say "A basic open set is a set of the form $(r,s)$  or $(0,r)\cup (s,2\pi]$ for $0<r<s\leq 2\pi$", I agree with the first one, but the second is the complement of the first one, so a closed set, isn't it?

Comment: @mathlover sets can be both opened and closed, they are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @ ccroth  ok, why is the second one open then?

Comment: I see it it's complement is closed, i guess the question was why we need to worry about two different types of open sets?

Comment: Thanks for helpful clarifications @ccroth. Yes, my identification of $S^1/\mathscr{R}$ is in terms of equivalence classes: the upper half circle is $(0,\pi)$ where the classes are singletons, and $\ast$ is the class for the lower half. And for the topology on $S^1$: the basic open sets are "intervals" on the circle, which can "wrap around" angle $0$. A picture is helpful here. The complement of $(0,r)\cup (s,2\pi]$ is $[r,s]$, which is closed.

Comment: You need to consider the open sets of this latter kind for two reasons: (1) they *are open sets* and (2) you can't describe them using unions of open sets of the first kind.